# Bootstrap table with bootstrap toggle and sortable feature

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable, bootstrap-table

I hope you will interstand my issue.
I'm new to jquery and bootstrap framework. However, i'm trying to use Bootstrap toggle plugin in a bootstrap table.
And moreover, i want this table be sortable with these ON/OFF switches.

http://jsfiddle.net/hL7kb3jx/

```
<table data-toggle="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">Test</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>$1</td>
        <td><input id="toggle-demo" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>$2</td>
        <td><input id="toggle-demo" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>$3</td>
        <td><input id="toggle-demo" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"></td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
```

The first problem is when i click on header to sort column, the toggles are destroyed ???
Secondly, the column containing the toggles aren't sorted...
If Bootstrap-switch is a better idea, it's not a problem.

I will be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console when loading the table?